# Strange System of Equations or a matter of divisibility

Tags: combinatorics

A vendor sales oranges. They sale them in a very specific way:

$3$ for $\$5$

$4$ for $\$6$

$5$ for $\$7$

If they sold $100$ oranges for $\$160$, how many total sales did they make? (hint: $30$ sales)

Can this be solved without a system of linear equations? In other words, what is the simplest possible solution?

Comment: (1) We have to assume that we can not buy less than 3. (2) We have to simplify the Case that we can not buy more than 5. Otherwise , when buying 12 , we can not make out whether it is "3 sales of 4 items" or "4 sales of 3 items" or Etc. (3) We have Diophantine System with Integer Solution here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us Consider the Case where almost all ( $3 \times 32 = 96$ ) were sold in groups of 3 @ $5 ,

except the last $100 - 96 = 4$ which were sold in group of 4 @ $6

We get Dollar total $5 \times 32 + 6 \times 1 = 160 + 6 = 166$ which is 6 more than what we want.

Now we want to Exchange groups of 3 with groups of 5 :
$15 = 3 \times 5$ will cost $5 \times 5 = 25$
$15 = 5 \times 3$ will cost $7 \times 3 = 21$
That Exchange will reduce the Dollar total by $25-21=4$ which is still give 2 more than what we want.

Now we want to Exchange groups of 3 with groups of 4 :
$12 = 3 \times 4$ will cost $5 \times 4 = 20$
$12 = 4 \times 3$ will cost $6 \times 3 = 18$
That Exchange will reduce the Dollar total by $20-18=2$ which is Exactly what what we want.

Hence , group of 3 is $32-4-5=23$ , group of 4 is $1+3=4$ , group of 5 is $3$ which gives total $23+4+3=30$ groups.

Dollar : $23 \times 5 + 4 \times 6 + 3 \times 7 = 115 + 24 + 21 = 160$

I mentioned in my Earlier Comment , that we have Diophantine System of Equations with Integer Solution ( Non-Negative ) , & we have to Solve it that way using Equations.

I have added this Answer because OP wants Solution without Equations & because OP wants Simplest Solution.

Answer (score 4):

Let $a,b,c$ be the number of sales at the three rates, then

$3a + 4b + 5c = 100 \tag 1$

$5a + 6b + 7a = 160 \tag 2$

(2) -(1) gives $2a+2b+2c=60 \tag 3$

Thus $a+b+c = \boxed{30}$